# Why is Flask ignoring Cache-Control?

Tags: python, flask, cache-control

I am running a Flask application that includes an hourly process which updates a json variable in memory, and includes that variable in its response template. I've encountered the following unexpected behavior:

1. Initial visits to the web page show the data that was instantiated when the server was initiated only. The most recent hourly update of the data is ignored.
2. Rapidly hitting reload 5-10 times will bring the browser up-to-date and show the most recent json data (reloading just once or twice has no effect).
3. After the browser shows the most recent data, hitting reload again will revert back to the initial update as though it were cached.

Server Code:

```
data = None 
def updatejson():

    global data
    data = redditapi()

updatejson()

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=updatejson, trigger="interval", minutes=60)
scheduler.start()
atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    global data
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)

@app.after_request
def add_header(r):
    r.headers["Cache-Control"]  = "no-store"
    return r

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I have also tried setting the headers below, but same behavior:

```
    r.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, public, max-age=0'"
    r.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    r.headers["Expires"] = "0"
```

The index.html template also has this meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Confirmed response headers are correct on client side:

```
Cache-Control:no-store
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 26 Dec 2019 19:49:15 GMT
Server:nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

**Edit:**
curl -I reports the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 26 Dec 2019 22:24:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://pcsalesapp.com/
```

Tried adding expires -1 and Cache Control to Nginx but behavior persists:

```
location / {
    expires -1;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/jv/pcsalesapp/pcsalesapp.sock;
}
```

Do I need to address this in uwsgi as well?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use [`r.cache_control`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.cache_control)?

Comment: Do you get the expected results with curl or wget? Could be your browser rather than your app.

Comment: If you have nginx server it can cache requests to some pages too. You need to look to Flask output - do it receive all requests of yours?

Comment: Indeed the problem could be with Nginx or uWSGI. See edit above for nginx location details. Unsure how to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0):

This right way to set cache-control for your case is:

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(r):
    r.headers["Cache-Control"]  = "no-store max-age=0"
    return r
```

`no-store` will only prevent new resource from being cached, but it will not prevent the cache from responding with a resource from an earlier request. Setting `max-age=0` will force the cache to revalidate.

Also, setting cache-control the following way is a bad way to achieve this, and that's why it didn't work:

`r.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, public, max-age=0'"`